# Jupyter Notebook error: can't decode byte 0X9d in position 229858: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, position, jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyter notebook that is automatically being converted to a .py file when saved. I recently started getting this error while trying to save:

Unexpected error while running post hook save: 'charmap' codec can't decode bye 0x9d in position 229966: character maps to undefined

I figure the first step is to find where those characters are, but what does "position" mean for a Jupyter notebook? Is this similar to a line?

Comment: The position in this case most likely refers to the 229858th character in the file. The only times I see this error referenced are when a file written in utf8 encoding is read as unicode. I can;t add an answer, but I have no idea what the fix is, but check for special characters in your code.

Comment: Maybe you have some special character like üöä in there?

Comment: It was special quotes.  It took forever to find because the file was extremely long. I wonder if there is an easy way to spot this.